# Equality of conditional expectations $E(X_i\mid Y)$ and $E(X_j\mid Y)$ when $Y=g(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Which condition ensures that $E(X_i|g(X_1,...,X_n)) = E(X_j|g(X_1,...,X_n))$, other than $i = j$, where $X_1, ..., X_n$ are random variables and $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function?

Comment: The natural condition you probably have in mind is that $X=(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ is i.i.d. A weaker one, less natural, is that $(X_i,X)$ and $(X_j,X)$  are identically distributed (for example because $X$ would be exchangeable).